reading and writing midi files in Android studio
I want my application to save midi files to the internal storage of the device, but when I save the file, it does not open in the standard Windows player, but opens in musescore. From this we can conclude that most of the data is still correct
        try {
            midiFile = new MidiFile(file);
            midiFile.writeToFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/download/file.mid"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("midifile", "open failed");
        }

I compared the original and the resulting files bit by bit and it turned out that some bits had changed
Difference at byte: 22 74 72
Difference at byte: 1182 39 38
Difference at byte: 5441 103 101
Difference at byte: 10276 104 103
what can it be related to and how is it.
Also, everything works correctly in IntelliJ IDEA

Can you clarify where MidiFile came from, i.e. which library you used (link appreciated) or what classes/code are in MidiFile.

I couldn't find the original link and was making some changes to some classes. So here is the link to google drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cke32wv9Kalxp-P3XGVPDJbncasLWAct?usp=drive_link

Please edit your post to include relevant parts. Linking to your project on a third-party storage site won't help future readers should it no longer become available. Best would be a Minimal Reproducible Example
